# Any book recommended for learning bash script?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, script

I have learned Java, C++, python.
But recently I need to write some bash script.

Is there any book for learning bash script? Not bash command.

Comment: FYI, There's no difference between Unix shell commands and shell scripting. The simplest shell scripts start as pasting a set of commands into a text file, just like you'd enter them at the shell prompt. Sure, you're not as likely to use if/thens and loops at the shell prompt, but they work the same way at the prompt as they do from a script file. Also, note that using syntax specific to one shell (such as bash) is considered poor form for shell scripts. It's better to write in the more universal POSIX Bourne shell (/bin/sh) syntax so that it can execute correctly in any shell.

Answer (score 4):

The Linux Documentation Project has a VERY nice BASH guide online.  They call it the "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide," but I think it is appropriate for beginners.  This is my recommendation.  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Answer (score 1):

From #bash /topic on irc.freenode.net:

- FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ
- Guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810716/looking-for-book-on-bash-scripting) which I think it will help you to choose between the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) by Lhunath.
and [Advanced Bash Scripting](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html) by Mendel Cooper on *The Linux Documentation Project* website.

In general, *BashGuide* is preferred for the beginner and it's very short - only 90 pages!

After that, you can also find a lots of useful information on [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).